# Проверить доступность шар "с$" и "admin$" на локальных тачках

Tags: сервер, администрирование, windows-xp

на хосте 120 компов..надо проверить доступность шар **"с$" и "admin$"** чтобы в них GPO накатывались обновы, вручную - некомильфо, может кто нибудь подскажет бантиком как проикрутить это все? начал пробовать **net view.** Но он выводит только ip  и имя компа в сети..

Comment: то есть можно ли написать скрипт который будет проверять доступность этих шар, а результат складывать в txt. Если кттото сталкивался буду признателен ооочень.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот вопрос относится к системному администрированию

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, цитата из справки: Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и **системных администраторов.**

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, как не странно, но вы правы. Привожу ссылку, где есть аналогичное утверждение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Команда net share
В cmd ест-но

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?